# Combine array ignoring empty values?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm trying to extract values from the following array into a new array:

I received help with the `foreach` command, but am now having trouble combining two arrays, one of which has `null` values.

The original array is: http://pastebin.com/jeKVxpka

Using the following:

```
foreach ($arr['products']['product'] as $num) {

    $pid = $num['pid'];

    foreach($num['configoptions']['configoption']['0']['options']['option'] as $option)
        {
            $name = $option['name'];
            $yearlycosts = $option['pricing']['GBP']['monthly'];

            $namearr[] = $name;
            $yearlyarr[] = $yearlycosts;

            $peryear = array_combine($namearr, $yearlyarr);

        }

    $pricing[$pid] = array('cost' => $peryear);

}   

print_r($pricing);
```

I've been able to produce the following array:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [cost] => Array
                (
                    [1 Year] => 4.17
                    [2 Years] => 8.33
                    [3 Years] => 12.50
                    [4 Years] => 16.67
                    [5 Years] => 20.83
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [cost] => Array
                (
                    [1 Year] => 40.83
                    [2 Years] => 8.33   <---
                    [3 Years] => 12.50     |--- These values shouldn't be here!
                    [4 Years] => 16.67     |
                    [5 Years] => 20.83  <---
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [cost] => Array
                (
                    [1 Year] => 49.17
                    [2 Years] => 79.17
                    [3 Years] => 115.83
                    [4 Years] => 149.17
                    [5 Years] => 190.83
                )

        )

)
```

The problem is, if you look at the original array, there is no price information for product ID `[3]`. Years 2 to 5 have been populated with the values from years 2 to 5 for product ID `[2]`.

I've experimented with `array_filter` and `unset`, but I can't figure out how to prevent this from happening (or why it is happening).

Comment: Why are you doing `array_combine` each time through the loop, instead of when the loop is done?

Comment: That seems so obviously wrong now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to empty the arrays before the inner loops, so you don't keep the values from the previous iteration of the main loop. And you should do the `array_combine` outside the inner loop.

```
foreach ($arr['products']['product'] as $num) {

    $pid = $num['pid'];

    $namearr = array();
    $yearlyarr = array();

    foreach($num['configoptions']['configoption']['0']['options']['option'] as $option)
        {
            $name = $option['name'];
            $yearlycosts = $option['pricing']['GBP']['monthly'];

            $namearr[] = $name;
            $yearlyarr[] = $yearlycosts;

        }

    $peryear = array_combine($namearr, $yearlyarr);
    $pricing[$pid] = array('cost' => $peryear);

}   

print_r($pricing);
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you. Since I'm new to arrays, I assumed that they would be empty since they haven't been defined yet.

Comment: They are empty before they're defined. But after the first time through the loop, they're defined, so they're not empty any more. Variables in PHP are not local to a particular loop; variable scoping in PHP is by function or class, not finer-grained blocks.

Comment: I see. That's helped me better understand why my code wasn't working as expected. Thanks again, appreciate the help (and explanations).